# Installing ArcGIS for server 10.1 on linux server

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, installation, linux

I am trying to install ArcGIS for server 10.1 on my linux system. When I run "./startserver.sh" I get following error:

> ERROR: Unable to start Xvfb on any port in the range 6600 - 6619.

I have checked "xvfb_err.log" and this is the issue I found there:

> /root/arcgis/server//framework/runtime/xvfb/RHEL/Xvfb: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libXfont.so.1: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install all the [required packages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000072000000#ESRI_SECTION2_562E9E607E46435A9578D2A57327724C). libXfont provides libXfont.so.1 (be certain you have the .i386 package).

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this answer because this topic shows up as a top hit for a similar problem.  When we were doing an install using Centos instead of RedHat, we had a similar problem starting.  However, instead of missing a library, the error was something along the lines of

> /root/arcgis/server//framework/runtime/xvfb/Ubuntu/Xvfb: No such file or directory

The error comes as a result of the `init_xvfb.sh` script trying to figure out what Linux distro it is running on.  Just comment out lines 74 and 75 in the script as shown below.  This will cause it to run the RHEL binary, and everything appears to work from there.

```
# try to use the system one if it's there
if [ -f /usr/bin/Xvfb ]; then
  XVFBBIN=/usr/bin/Xvfb
elif [ -f /usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb ]; then
  XVFBBIN=/usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb
else
# fall back to our own
if [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
    XVFBBIN="${XVFBHOME}/SuSE/Xvfb"
#elif [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
#  XVFBBIN="${XVFBHOME}/Ubuntu/Xvfb"
else
    XVFBBIN="${XVFBHOME}/RHEL/Xvfb"
fi
fi
```

Comment: Be careful!  CentOS is *not* an Esri-supported platform.  I found this out the hard way when a CentOS 6.x security patch released somewhen before 06 Jan 2014 caused ArcGIS 10.1sp1+QIP to stop working (and it corrupted all the services, forcing a complete reinstall/republish).  I had to install RHEL 6.x to revive my stricken AGS instances.